# Is there a workaround for Firefox 5 and Chrome ”setInterval()” and “setTimeout()” in inactive tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, settimeout, setinterval

There is a JavaScript optimization that causes inactive tabs to slow down `setInterval()` and setTimeout()` in Firefox 5 and Chrome. I have it set for 66 miliseconds but it goes up to 1,000 when a tab is inactive.

There is way to determine how much time passed when the tab was inactive? I need JavaScript to keep running and performing actions, like playing sounds for some events.

Is there any way to achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of those clamps is to keep background pages from using too much CPU.  What events, exactly do you have going on in 15Hz that need to play sounds even though the user can't see the tab?

Comment: I see the reason why is this limitation in place. We're playing sth like virtul footbla match in browser and real second last there only 66ms. In every 66ms there are some actions to take place like moving the clocks or some event is taking place

Comment: @Michal Kikta Can you not just coalesce updates if the heartbeat timer doesn't fire at 15Hz?  That is, in a background tab the timer would fire every second and you would do all the work for 15s worth of play.

Comment: coalescation is the answer, it came to my mind. I can group all the 15 actions in one second to happem at once and  it won't be difference for user as far as he is at another tab. This can be done with some not too long code and no significant chcanges to app, thx

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla is working on a different way of implementing setInterval and setTimeout, called requestAnimationFrame, perhaps it could help you solve your problem, or atleast hope for future updates that will take care of the problem.

Note that it is an experimental feature, beware of limitations when seeking cross-browser support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame

Comment: it looks praety decent and it's being implemented in both chorme and ff, but it looks like to slow down in inactive tab

Comment: "The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation. The callback rate may be reduced to a lower rate when running in background tabs." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame