# JavaScript animation not behaving when switch browser tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Live site: http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org/
I'm trying to make a carousel effect by jQuery. Please be noted to better understand what is going on, you have to reduce the window height.

The problem is: If you keep looking at the page, the carousel goes well, but if you switch to another browser tab, wait for a few seconds, and then switch back, you will see the carousel gets displaced. The longer you stay at other browser tab, the more it is displaced.

It seems the problem is coming from this function:

```
function getRelativeClientRect(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
      parentRect = el.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    bottom: parentRect.bottom - rect.bottom,
    height: rect.height,
    left: rect.left - parentRect.left,
    right: parentRect.right - rect.right,
    top: rect.top - parentRect.top,
    width: rect.width
  };
}
```

which I got from this SO question: [How do I get the actual values for left/right/top/bottom of an absolutely positioned element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891892/how-do-i-get-the-actual-values-for-left-right-top-bottom-of-an-absolutely-positi).

The following are the HTML and codes of my site:
HTML:

```
<div class='marquee-container'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/1.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/2.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/3.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/4.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('images/5.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.image-container{position:absolute;transition:all 1s ease;  display: -webkit-box;display: -moz-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;}
.image{float:left;background-size:cover;cursor:pointer}
```

JS:There are two related JS scripts,the first one is located before closing body tag, I use it to make the images auto fit the height of screen

```
<script>
        (function(){
            var width, height = true;

            function initHeader() {
            headerHeight = document.getElementById('rt-header')? document.getElementById('rt-header').getHeight():0;
                width = window.innerWidth;
                height = window.innerHeight - headerHeight;
                largeHeader = document.getElementById('rt-topfullwidth');
                largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

                j('.marquee-container').height(height);
                j('.marquee-container .image').height(height);

            }

            // Main
            initHeader();
        })();
    </script>
```

The seconde one is located at http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org/templates/rt_chimera/js/custom.js, I use it to implement the carousel effect. I know its readability is low, so I have added some comments to it.

Comment: See here: [workaround for FF5 and chrome setInterval(), setTimeout() in inactive tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943947/workaround-for-ff5-and-chrome-setinterval-settimeout-in-inactive-tab)

Answer (score 0):

After looking on the behavior on the site online, my best bet is that the browser optimizes CPU by not playing all the frames of the transition while the tab is not visible, and catches up on the current frame when the tab becomes visible again, which causing the flickering on the screen.

What reinforces this theory is that the bug happens on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

I think a possible solution to workaround the issue is to implement the animation in JavaScript instead of CSS... or to wait for Chrome to fix the issue.

Comment: If the 'bug' you mentioned is referring to the problem I'm having, I have it on firefox too

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with setTimeout and setInterval. Chrome doesn't properly keep track of the timers for setTimeout and setInterval if you switch to a different tab. I guess the intention is to improve the browser's performance, but in this case, it's clearly not what you wanted. I don't think the chrome team intends to 'fix' this.

Comment: It does indeed. set an interval running logs in your console and you'll see logs poping even when switching tab